# which codec will be used with mjpeg file?

Tags: html, video

I need to embed and play an mjpeg video with an html file. I can use  tag. The container is either .mp4 or .avi.
Which codecs should I use to play the videos?

Answer (score 0):

h264 (the codec generally used by .mp4) is becoming the standard for playing video in HTML5. Even Firefox is finally starting to support it.

Comment: Yes. Wherever I searched, I found that it is h264 type only. but for playing mjpeg which particular codecs should I mention?

Like for .mkv file, it a_ac3 and avc

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you are asking, then. You say you are going to put it into a .mp4 or a .avi container, and want to know the codec to use. h264 is the codec, and .mp4 is probably the best container to use for the most universal support. MJPEG I believe is a different codec altogether, so you'd have to transcode it, unfortunately.